# Overriding an article output in Drupal 7 using a template.php theme

Tags: php, html, drupal

I basically want to modify the output of my articles, by putting a

---

between each article that is listed on my page.

I have overridden other functions in my themes template.php as follows

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
    drupal_add_css('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gudea', array('type' => 'external'));
}
```

I am looking for something similar for the articles?

Answer (score 0):

Copy your theme's `node.tpl.php` to a file called `node--article.tpl.php` and add an `&lt;hr&gt;` at the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Views module? Take a look http://drupal.org/project/views and use it to list content for you. Views can create a Page display for this content. You can then apply styles to the Views-generated HTML that will allow you to put dividing borders between the nodes listed. Views provides 'first' and 'last' classes as well so that you will not apply a border to the last element.